# Erro ao fazer appendChild numa variavel

Tags: javascript, html

```
Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('12:35:41') is not a valid name.'
```

```js
window.onload = function startTime() {
  let today = new Date();
  let h = today.getHours();
  let m = today.getMinutes();
  let s = today.getSeconds();
  // add a zero in front of numbers<10
  m = checkTime(m);
  s = checkTime(s);
 
  let tempo = document.createElement( h + ":" + m + ":" + s );
    document.getElementById('time').appendChild(tempo);
  
  t = setTimeout(function() {
    startTime()
  }, 500);
  
}
function obterHoras() {
    // Objecto Javascript que nos permite utilziar alguns métodos
    // para obtermos as diferentes componentes da data / hora 
    // (dias, mes, ano, horas, minutos, etc)
    let fullDate = new Date();

    // Criação de variáveis para armazenamento das horas e minutos
    let horas = fullDate.getHours();
    // let minutos = fullDate.getMinutes();

    return horas;
}
```

[image]

Comment: O que você espera que linha faça: `let tempo = document.createElement( h + ":" + m + ":" + s );`

Comment: criar uma variavel para atribuir ao getElementById('time') o seu valor

Comment: Leia a mensagem de erro. Jogue num tradutor se precisar. Em HTML não existe a tag `<12:35:41>`, que é o que você mandou criar.

Comment: Dê uma olhada na documentação, [Document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A função `CreateElement("TagName")` espera como parâmetro o nome de um elemento DOM e em seu código o parâmetro é algo como: 11:02:00.
Então adicione esse texto em um elemento **p**, **div** ou **text node**

```
let time = document.createElement("div")
time.innerText = hora
document.getElementById("time").appendChild(time)
```